# Javascript syntax in backbone source code

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

What does this code do?

```
g = "undefined" !== typeof exports ? exports : k.Backbone = {};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It defines Backbone as a CommonJS module, so it can be loaded in CommonJS compatible environments such as node.js.

You're looking at the minified source code. This is what it looks like [unminified](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html):

```
var Backbone;
if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
  Backbone = exports;
} else {
  Backbone = root.Backbone = {};
}
```

The variable `exports` is the return object defined by CommonJS modules. In CommonJS environments the `Backbone` variable is set to that value, so `Backbone` is exported from the module.

If `exports` is undefined, it is assumed that the code is in the browser environment, and `Backbone` should be exported a property on the `root` object, which refers to `window`, the browser´s global scope.

Answer (score 3):

It's shorthand for:

```
if("undefined" !== typeof exports)
    g = exports;
}else{
    g = k.Backbone = {};
}
```

The `:?` is called a [Ternary Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a)

Maybe it's a little more readable if I'd write it this way:

```
g = ("undefined" !== typeof exports) // If
    ? exports                        // Then
    : k.Backbone = {};               // Else
```